# Unity ProBuilder Grid Blocks Erase

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, builder

[Unity House Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3R53.png)

Hi guys, I was making a building using Unity ProBuilder and wanted to add a finishing touch. I was wondering how to polish the building so that there will be no grid in the building itself (as you can see that the building from the floor to the roof have grids / blocks surrounding it. Anyone can help me with that? I tried googling but non came up

Comment: The grid is only in the editor. Its not visible runtime

Comment: It's still there even when I run it tho, or do I need code it more first?

Comment: Oh. Then you need to change the material.

Comment: What do you mean? I started the building from scratch using the pro builder tool in Unity, is there any other tools/packages for that or in ProBuilder is there an option for doing so???

Comment: Yes but the material on the things you make you need to change. And no. You dont need other tools for that

Comment: When you mean the material, you mean like the plane, cube, etc right? How do you change the material tho???

Comment: Please find a tutorial as its way too much to go through on here

Comment: So sorry for the late respond, I kept getting confused on what the material is lmao, I thought what you're talking about is the shape, but it turns out it was the "material" for the shape. It all works now, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks BugFinder for giving me the info that I needed and sorry for not solving this question much earlier because I was too focused on continuing my code ahahaha. Turns out I kept getting confused on what the material is lmao, I thought that the material was the shape of the object I'm making but and then I realized it is the material for "building" the shape. It's all done and resolved now!!!